# Using WebWorkers in Typescript with Webpack and worker-loader without custom loader strings

Tags: typescript, webpack, web-worker

I'm trying to get web workers playing nice with Typescript and Webpack's [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader). There's an example in their documentation of achieving this through a custom module declaration, however this relies on using the webpack `worker-loader!./myWorker` syntax.

I want to be able to load workers through a custom `*.worker.js` webpack `use` rule rather than explicitly listing the loader in the import string. Something about typescript doesn't seem to like defining or modifying a modules declaration if it's a plain relative import, and gets stuck on the fact that the worker file is not a module, even with a module declaration for it.

I have a worker that looks like

```
// test.worker.ts
/// <reference lib="webworker" />

const worker: DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope = self as any;

worker.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
  if (data instanceof Array) {
    worker.postMessage(data.join(' ') + '!');
  }
};
```

A declaration that looks like

```
// custom.d.ts
declare module '*.worker' {
  class TestWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();
  }

  export default TestWorker
}
```

And is used in my main app as

```
import TestWorker from './test.worker';

const testWorker = new TestWorker();
testWorker.onmessage = ({ data }: { data: string }) => {
  console.log(data);
};

testWorker.postMessage([
  'hello',
  'I',
  'am',
  'a',
  'web',
  'worker',
]);
```

The error output is

```
TypeScript error in /worker-test/src/index.tsx(9,24):File '/worker-test/src/test.worker.ts' is not a module.  TS2306
```

Changing the import to `worker-loader!./test.worker` seems to work and gets typescript to understand the custom declaration, however I'm really trying to avoid using custom loader strings as the intention is to integrate this into create-react-app which doesn't allow these.

Is there a way to get regular relative imports to recognise a custom module declaration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were almost there!

Change the module declaration to include the file extension:

```
// custom.d.ts
declare module '*.worker.ts' {
  class TestWorker extends Worker {
    constructor();
  }

  export default TestWorker
}
```

And your import to also include the file extension:

```
import TestWorker from './test.worker.ts';
```

This did it for me - specifying the extension in the import stops TS from importing it as a module, and specifying the extension in the declaration stops TS from complaining since you're importing a `.ts` file by also specifying the extension.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this is necessary as basically every other can leave the `.ts` off, which is especially useful in a mixed js/ts/tsx environment. But given the special nature of workers and this override, this is by far the best tradeoff. Thanks for taking the time to answer!